Network device crashes after coral passthrough
I have an HP T630 thin client with proxmox installed. I connected coral using m.2 socket. I can see /dev/apex_0 device. Until that point everything is ok.
The problem starts when I set passthrough and start my VM with frigate. Then my ethernet device crashes, the LEDs stop blinking, and my node is disconnected from network. I need to restart for the network to work again. Setting network interface down and up does not help.
After restart if I start the VM the same error occurs.
When I remove coral passthrough and start VM everything is ok.
Do you have an idea what might be a problem? Where should I search to find solution?
I tried that instruction https://www.reddit.com/r/homeassistant/comments/xzajo0/comment/irnxouy/ but it didn't work .
lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) I/O Memory Management Unit
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Wani [Radeon R5/R6/R7 Graphics] (rev 88)
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kabini HDMI/DP Audio
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Host Bridge
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root Port
00:02.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root Port
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Host Bridge
00:08.0 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Carrizo Platform Security Processor
00:09.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Carrizo Audio Dummy Host Bridge
00:09.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Audio Controller
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 20)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 49)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 49)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 4a)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Function 5
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
02:00.0 System peripheral: Global Unichip Corp. Coral Edge TPU

dmesg
[  102.477288] cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database
[  102.477943] Loaded X.509 cert 'benh@debian.org: 577e021cb980e0e820821ba7b54b4961b8b4fadf'
[  102.478398] Loaded X.509 cert 'romain.perier@gmail.com: 3abbc6ec146e09d1b6016ab9d6cf71dd233f0328'
[  102.478822] Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7'
[  102.479248] Loaded X.509 cert 'wens: 61c038651aabdcf94bd0ac7ff06c7248db18c600'
[  102.479390] platform regulatory.0: Direct firmware load for regulatory.db failed with error -2
[  102.479400] cfg80211: failed to load regulatory.db
[  102.524627] fwbr100i0: port 2(veth100i0) entered blocking state
[  102.524652] fwbr100i0: port 2(veth100i0) entered forwarding state
[  226.158154] VFIO - User Level meta-driver version: 0.3
[  226.173438] vfio_pci: add [1ac1:089a[ffffffff:ffffffff]] class 0x000000/00000000
[  226.176068] r8169 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0: Link is Down
[  226.184304] vmbr0: port 1(enp1s0) entered disabled state
[  226.184732] r8169 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0 (unregistering): left allmulticast mode
[  226.184745] r8169 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0 (unregistering): left promiscuous mode
[  226.184756] vmbr0: port 1(enp1s0) entered disabled state
[  228.451292] tap108i0: entered promiscuous mode
[  228.491034] vmbr0: port 1(tap108i0) entered blocking state
[  228.491046] vmbr0: port 1(tap108i0) entered disabled state
[  228.491088] tap108i0: entered allmulticast mode
[  228.491217] vmbr0: port 1(tap108i0) entered blocking state
[  228.491223] vmbr0: port 1(tap108i0) entered forwarding state
[  229.294899] vfio-pci 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0100 -> 0102)

My network interface is vmbr0 and i see in dmesg 'vmbr0: port 1(enp1s0) entered disabled state' but is that the root cause? How to fix it?
I tried also that https://first2host.co.uk/blog/how-to-fix-proxmox-detected-hardware-unit-hang/ but without any effect.
root@NODE:~# dmesg | grep "Link is Up"
[   33.156677] r8169 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
root@NODE:~# ethtool -K enp1s0 tso off gso off 


Questions should demonstrate reasonable information technology management practices. Questions that relate to unsupported hardware or software platforms or unmaintained environments may not be suitable for Server Fault. However, why do you want to pass a NIC through?

I believe it's not about NIC passthrough, but about a Coral TPU passthrough. Makes sense pretty well. The attempt to pass the TPU renders a NIC into non-operable state, which is strange.

@NikitaKipriyanov exactly this is the issue

@NikitaKipriyanov if i will not find any solution soon i would need to return Google Coral and replace HP T630 with something better.

Is there a reason you are using such a weird combination of hardware? Doing that and adding zero context is a top cause of question sclerosis.

@GregAskew i bought 2 HP T630 for home assistant and some play around. I installed Proxmox on both and created two node cheap lab. It is cheap and it's working. Now i bought camera and tested frigate. It works but take quite lot of cpu during detection. So i want to delegate detection work from cpu to Google Coral. This is my history :)

You need another forum like Reddit homelab. This is a mainstream planet Earth forum.

I fixed that. It was problem with iommu groups. Ethernet and google coral were in the same group.
